# Jquery CSS width after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the width of a div after using append in Jquery.

HTML:

```
<div id="myid"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
var uhm = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
$("#myid").append(uhm);
```

CSS:

```
#myid {
   width:200px;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/migueladan/8eXHT/

I need that the content of the variable stay within the width of the div (all in the red rectangle)

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you actually need? Because you have set fixed size of the div elem

Comment: do you need it to be 200px?

Comment: I need that the content of the variable stay within the width of the div (all in the red rectangle).

Comment: @user3314800 Do you want the extra a's to go to the next line or to be hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want;

```
#myid{
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8eXHT/9/

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the word-break:break-all; css property.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit unclear, what exactly you want.
But maybe [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/overflow) is what you are looking for.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8eXHT/3/) is an updated version of your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block;` to resize:

http://jsfiddle.net/8eXHT/5/

Use `overflow: hidden;` if it needs to remain 200px and you want to hide:

http://jsfiddle.net/8eXHT/1/

Use `word-break:break-all;` if it needs to remain 200px but it is allowed to increase in height:

http://jsfiddle.net/8eXHT/8/

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the word-break:break-all; css property.